# Css not working properly in codemirror editor

Tags: css, codemirror

I've installed the [codemirror editor](http://codemirror.net/) succesfully.
But there is one issue regarding css of that editor.

You can check [here](http://screencast.com/t/t3eLWrYvj) what I mean.

So how can I display the color after 3rd line in the editor.

Comment: Which version of CodeMirror is that? Which browser? And are you touching any CodeMirror-related css classes?

Comment: can you show your implementation? hard to answer by seeing screenshot.

Comment: Please answer @Marijn when you can because those answers are necessary to understand and solve your issue.

Comment: codemirror version is 3.8 in all browser no i have'nt touched any css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should look at

```
<div class="CodeMirror-gutters" style=" /*height: some_pixel*/; "><div class="CodeMirror-gutter CodeMirror-linenumbers" style="width: 28px;"></div></div>
```

instead of some_pixel after press enter or any keyword it will automatically set the height of the line number,
if you have that problem on start you might want to see how to create at first,
there is three common method,
The simplest is to define your Text Area and just use this code:

```
var YourCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(YourDefinedTextArea);
```

The best is put values using code:

```
var yourCodeMirror = CodeMirror(PlaceYouWant, {
  value: /*any code here :*/"function(){return 'anything'}",
  mode:  /*your mode ie.*/"javascript"
});
```

hope it helps
UPDATE: There is a manual site here : http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror parses HTML using the XML mode. To use it, the appropriate script must be included, same as with any other mode.

Add its dependency in your markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="/site.com/js/libs/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
```

and set the mode to xml:

```
config = {
    mode : "xml",
    // ...
};
```

In addition, you may want to configure the parser to allow for non well-formed XML. You can do so by switching the htmlMode flag on:

```
config = {
    mode : "xml",
    htmlMode: true,
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Including .../codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js made my HTML coloring work.